# Passing function with arguments to a signal handler?

Tags: c, posix

I can successfully pass a function to signal(), but I cannot come up with a way to pass an argument to a function without using `static` or a global variable.  `functionontimer` just updates an array.

```
if (signal(SIGALRM, (void (*)(int)) functionontimer) == SIG_ERR) 
{
return(-1);
}
```

Is there any way to pass a pointer along with the function without using `static` or a global variable?  I would ideally see  functiontimer be defined something like `functiontimer(int *data, index)`.

Comment: Use [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with `SA_SIGINFO` instead.

Comment: @Myst, `sigaction()` does not help here.  Yes, it allows use of a signal handler with a different (specific) signature, but it does not support the OP's objective of passing user data into the handler.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , That's true, except perhaps, for IO signals. That's why I wrote it in a comment rather than an answer. `signal` should be considered deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: @Myst, I'm not following you with respect to I/O signals.  `sigaction()` allows you to choose between two signatures for the signal-handler function.  In either case, the parameters convey information about the signal, not arbitrary data chosen by the program.  As for `signal()` being considered deprecated, you may have that freedom if you need only support POSIX-conforming environments, but C itself defines only `signal()`, not `sigaction()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , thank you for pointing this out. I tend to ignore non-POSIX environments to my own demise. Today I learned that using `signal` is probably the most conforming option. As for IO signals, I was referencing `asio` as a possible exception, which is obviously another beast, not related to `sigaction`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ... I re-read my notes on `signal` and the C standard regarding the function... I return to my previous understanding that `signal`'s behavior can't be trusted. When available, `sigaction` should probably be preferred, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to pass a pointer along with the function without using `static` or a global variable? I would ideally see functiontimer be defined something like `functiontimer(int *data, index)`

No, there is not, and if you force in a function that expects an additional argument, such as by casting it as you show in your example, then undefined behavior ensues when the system calls it with the number and type of arguments it expects to use instead of the number and type of arguments that the function is actually defined to receive.

It's unclear for what purpose you want the proposed behavior, but it may well be that signal handling does not serve that purpose.  It certainly does not serve the purpose in the way you hope.

Comment: I see, and I believe it.  The fundamental problem that I have is Linux and not changing the base architecture of a program.  I'm trying to port code that used kevent and then Grand Central Dispatch to Linux, but keep tree compatibility between future releases to Linux.  I thought that answer would be POSIX, but Linux includes POSIX extensions and BSDs do not.  I just need a function that runs every 100ms that can take an argument, and it's much more challenging then I expected.

Comment: @bdegnan, would [a Linux implementation of kevent/kqueue](https://github.com/mheily/libkqueue) help?

Comment: @bdegnan , I found that moving "timers" into user space was the most effective approach (that's what I did for [facil.io](http://facil.io/0.7.x/fio#timer-functions), switching from `kqueue`/`epoll` was fairly easy)... that's assuming you have an event loop running somewhere.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's this weird trifecta of supporting everything that is needed.  GCD is pretty nice and BSD moved away from kevent. I could just use pthreads and sleep.  It's really just more of I figured someone had a nice way to handle this, and it wasn't easily found on google.  This means that it's the wrong way to do it (as you described).  I just need to see if someone else has had an epiphany regarding this.  I will also look at Myst's approach.